# Https google news error (specific date)

Tags: c#, https

I am trying to parse google news for specific days in the past
although **the request works**, it returns the live news (not for the specific days I enter). I tried everything but nothing works.

```
string url = "https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=keyword&hl=en-
             CY&biw=1280&bih=620&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" + 
             prev_date.Month.ToString() + "%2F" + prev_date.Day.ToString() 
             + "%2F" + prev_date.Year.ToString() + "%2Ccd_max%3A" + 
             date.Month.ToString() + "%2F" + date.Day.ToString() + "%2F" + 
              date.Year.ToString() + "&tbm=nws";

           StreamReader reader = null;
            WebRequest request = null;
            WebResponse response = null;
             request = WebRequest.Create(url);
             request.Method = "GET";
             response = request.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), 
                                      Encoding.UTF8);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime prev_date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1);
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 30);

        string url = @"http://www.google.com.cy/search?q=keyword&hl=en-CY&biw=1280&bih=620&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" + 
            prev_date.Month.ToString() + "%2F" + prev_date.Day.ToString() 
            + "%2F" + prev_date.Year.ToString() + "%2Ccd_max%3A" + 
            date.Month.ToString() + "%2F" + date.Day.ToString() + "%2F" + 
            date.Year.ToString() + "&tbm=nws";

        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        Stream sr = client.OpenRead(url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sr);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\test.htm", reader.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close ();
    }
}
```

I think google returns different results depending on the UserAgent.